# primitive datatypes are atomic in java

Tags: java, race-condition, atomic

I read that primitive datatypes like boolean, byte, short, char, int and float are atomic. 64-bit datatypes like long and double are not.

But what does this mean? When I have 2 Threads that increment and decrement on a int variable than sometimes i still got race conditions.

for example the bytecode of adding an amount to a variable.

```
getfield #2 <Field int amount>
iload_1
iadd
putfield #2 <Field int amount>
```

Is atomic in this case every single operation (getfield, iadd...) and not the full addition?

Comment: Atomic means that an operation that changes the value  happens "at once" like a transaction. That doesn't mean that you won't have race conditions, it just means that you won't have race conditions because of atomicy.

Comment: Yes i read the Are java primitive ints atomic by design or by accident? but I was not sure thats why i asked explicit if "getfield", "iload_1" is atomic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When I have 2 Threads that increment and decrement on a int variable than sometimes i still got race conditions.

Yes, you will - because even though the "get" and "set" operations on the `int` variable are each atomic, that doesn't mean the "increment" operation is atomic.

> Is atomic in this case every single operation (getfield, iadd...) and not the full addition?

Yes, exactly. It's not actually the primitive *types* are atomic - it's read and write operations that are atomic. That's a big difference.